# GWT: Tree widget inside a stackpanel shifts entire app up when clicked

Tags: gwt, tree, stackpanel

I have a tree widget defined as follows:

```
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        TreeItem root = new TreeItem("asdf");
    root.setSelected(true);
    root.addItem(new TreeItem("blah"));
    root.addItem(new TreeItem("blue"));
    root.addItem(new TreeItem("blahblah"));
    root.addItem(new TreeItem("dada"));
```

I then add the tree to my stackpanel using .add().

When I click on any node in the tree panel..the entire app is shifted up to the top of the window, with the selected node at the very top.  I don't have any clickhandlers attached.  How can I stop this action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `addDomHandler()` is part of the `Widget` class.

`TreeItem` does **not** extend `Widget` class.

Try the proposed workaround on the `Tree` class itself which extends `Widget` calss